# How to apply a 'Loop' to map the row element where XPath changes whenever page get's loaded

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, xpath

How to map on to a particular row element say " NCC "where the number of the row containing that element changes whenever page get's loaded.

[Reference website-guru99](http://demo.guru99.com/test/web-table-element.php)

```
for(int i=0;i<19;i++) 
       {
           System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("///*
[@id="leftcontainer"]/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[1]/a")).getText());
        }
```

unable to loop through the XPath.

Comment: Why are you using absolute xpath , use relative xpath with contains[text(),"NCC"]

Comment: Use explicit wait for the text to be present ,